# Encode and Decode Manually where the type nested in a container is an array

Tags: json, swift, encoding, decoding

I am trying to encode and decode where the structure of my JSON does not match the structure of my class. I came across [this Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) that states the following under the "Encode and Decode Manually" section:

> If the structure of your Swift type differs from the structure of its encoded form, you can provide a custom implementation of Encodable and Decodable to define your own encoding and decoding logic.

This sounds like exactly what I'm looking for but the example given doesn't directly address my situation. Here is the code from the Apple example:

```
struct Coordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var elevation: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude
        case longitude
        case additionalInfo
    }
    
    enum AdditionalInfoKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case elevation
    }
}

extension Coordinate: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        latitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        longitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
        
        let additionalInfo = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AdditionalInfoKeys.self, forKey: .additionalInfo)
        elevation = try additionalInfo.decode(Double.self, forKey: .elevation)
    }
}

extension Coordinate: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
        
        var additionalInfo = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: AdditionalInfoKeys.self, forKey: .additionalInfo)
        try additionalInfo.encode(elevation, forKey: .elevation)
    }
}
```

What this allows is to store the `elevation` property as part of the `Coordinate` struct even though in the JSON it is nested in the `additionalInfo` container. So for instance, it could read this:

```
{
  "latitude": 123.4,
  "longitude": 432.1,
  "additionalInfo": {
    "elevation": 567.8
  }
}
```

Now, my question is, how would this code be adapted to a scenario where say each `Coordinate` has MULTIPLE `elevation` values in the `additionalInfo` container? (This may not make sense realistically, I just thought it would be easy to go off the existing example ).

So, if I had something like this...

```
{
  "latitude": 123.4,
  "longitude": 432.1,
  "additionalInfo": [
    {
      "elevation": 567.8
    },
    {
      "elevation": 876.5
    }
  ]
}
```

and I want my struct to look like this...

```
struct Coordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var elevations: [Double]
}
```

What would I have to change in the code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a helper struct `Info`

```
struct Info : Codable { let elevation : Double }
```

and to drop the nested container. Either decode a single `Info` instance and get the `elevation` value or decode an array and map it to an `elevation` array

```
struct Coordinate {
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
    var elevations: [Double]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case latitude
        case longitude
        case additionalInfo
    }
}

extension Coordinate: Decodable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        latitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .latitude)
        longitude = try values.decode(Double.self, forKey: .longitude)
        
        if let singleElevation = try? values.decode(Info.self, forKey: .additionalInfo) {
            self.elevations = [singleElevation.elevation]
        } else {
            self.elevations = try values.decode([Info].self, forKey: .additionalInfo).map(\.elevation)
        }
    }
}

extension Coordinate: Encodable {
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(latitude, forKey: .latitude)
        try container.encode(longitude, forKey: .longitude)
        let info = elevations.map(Info.init)
        try container.encode(info, forKey: .additionalInfo)
    }
}
```